# How to change Eddystone-UID Namespace ID

Tags: eddystone

How can I change Eddystone Namespace ID, or is there a way to change the namespace ID of an Eddystone URI? I have 2 forecum 201 beacons

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download their app, keep the beacons close to your phone and turn on your bluetooth and location.
Then you will be able to change the instance ID and Eddystone URL from within the app. Also, click apply after to change the setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the difference between Namespace ID and Instance ID, and I think that there's no way to change the namespace ID, only the instance ID.

Comment: Oh it is definitely possible to change the Instance ID as well as the namespace. Kontakt.io has a nice strategy guide for the same: https://kontakt.io/blog/beacon-id-strategy-guide-quick-deployment/